# unable to set cookies using document.cookie in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, cookies, firefox-addon

I am trying to create an extension(addon) for firefox which **creates a cookie from the background script of the extension which is then sent to the popup script** later. But for some reason, I can't create/save cookies from the background script(background.js).
I made the extension in chrome with the same method and it works there.

*This is what I get executing the code in the console of the addon:*

```
>> document.cookie = "cookieKey=cookieValue; expires=Tue, 14 Jul 2021 11:54:29 GMT; path=/";
   "cookieKey=cookieValue; expires=Tue, 14 Jul 2021 11:54:29 GMT; path=/"
>> document.cookie
   ""
```

I have provided the permission for the addon to the cookies as well.

This is what my manifest.json file looks like:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "hello world!!!",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/extension-icon.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "permissions": ["tabs", "cookies", "<all_urls>"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/extension-icon.png",
    "default_title": "Hello world!",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  }
}
```

This is what my try to do from background.js

```
dateInt = new Date().getTime() + 24*60*60*1000    //expire after 24 hours
expiry_date = "; expires="+new Date(dateInt).toUTCString()+"; path=/"

document.cookie = "a=" + data.a + expiry_date
document.cookie = "b=" + data.b + expiry_date
document.cookie = "c=" + data.c + expiry_date
document.cookie = "d=" + data.d+ expiry_date

console.log('cookie created: ', document.cookie)
```

But this is the output I see in the console:

```
cookie created:  <empty string>
```

I am confused why this won't work in firefox when there's no such problem in chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you try to set `document.cookie` from your background script. Cookies belong to a specific domain, and thus you cannot set it globally from a background script.

You should either change your code so that you set `document.cookie` inside your content script, or use the `cookies` [web extension API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies) (which can only be used from a background script, not content script anyways).
You then have to supply the URL that the cookie belongs to when setting it using `cookies.set({ url: "https://the.url/your/cookie/belongs/to", ... })`.